# Rails 4 nested_attributes with has_one association rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have two models in Rails 4 app with has_one association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :member
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :member
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I trying create User with Member.
This is my controller.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_member
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new member_params
    if @user.save
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  private

  def member_params
    params[:user].permit(:id, :name, :email, :password, :city, member_attributes: [ :position, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :user_id ])
  end
end
```

This is form. I using SimpleForm.

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :city
  = f.input :password
  = f.simple_fields_for :member, @user.member do |us|
    = us.input :position
    = us.input :avatar
  = f.button :submit
```

What part of my code is wrong?

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eqxcHlLrnKB9atm3YGG6WyMT429qqRr5zpB/LM4IMAI=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Павел", "email"=>"kalashnikov@ulmic.ru", "city"=>"Ульяновск", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "member_attributes"=>{"position"=>"123", "avatar_cache"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Создать User"}
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1 (0.3ms)  
BEGIN
User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'kalashnikov@ulmic.ru' LIMIT 1 (0.3ms)  
ROLLBACK
```

This code working in my projects on Rails 3, but there is not strong_parameters in Rails 3.

Comment: It looks like it is rollbacking because he finds another user already exists with the email that is probably set to be unique. If this is not the issue, is there an error in your server log that says forbidden parameter?

Comment: @irruputuncu yes! You're right! I has 
    `validates :user_id, presence: true`
in Member model.
It's working after removing this line!
Thanks!

Comment: Glad this could already solve your problem! I've just posted it as an answer too so this thread can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more likely to be an issue with validations than with strong parameters. In your case the  `user.email` seems to be constrained to be unique, but it could be anything on the `user` or `member` models. Of course a forbidden parameter can also be a reason a validation fails even though correct data is submitted, but in this case you'll see a message in the server logs (however no exception is thrown).